# Socket Hangup Error on node.js with sendgrid library

Tags: node.js, sockets, azure, sendgrid

I am getting `socket hang up` error while trying to make a POST call to the sendgrid server for sending out mails. When running the same code on another azure VM, it is working fine.

```
[WARN] [MAIL] Error sending mail { Error: socket hang up
at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:252:15)
at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:344:23)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:934:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' } null
```

I've tried application and server restart. But no help.
The firewall settings seems to be same for both the VM.

Would really appreciate if someone can help.
TIA

Comment: Which OS you use on the Azure VMs, Linux or Windows? What the Node.js version? And could you check whether you have any specific configurations about `Outbound security rules` in the problem VM?

Comment: Ubuntu 15.10, No Outbound Security Rules. The system was working perfectly fine, then all of a sudden it wasn't